# CSS Positioning with Text and Images on Same Line

Tags: css, margin, padding

How to I align my text and image on the same line?

Whenever I used padding or margins it crashes into the circle image I'm using.

```css
#alignPhoto {
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 400px;
}
#alignCompany {
  margin-left: 240px
}
#alignImage {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -250px;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #C3C3C3;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 42px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 42px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="alignPhoto">
  <div class="circle" id=image role="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/42x42">
  </div>
</div>
<div id=alignPhoto class="titleBoldText">Mary Smith</div>
<div id=alignCompany class="titleText">Morris Realty and Investments</div>
<br>
```

Currently It does this:

[image: Incorrect CSS]

My desired effect is this: 
[image: Correct CSS]

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Notice: you've got the id `#alignPhoto` twice.

Comment: start from writing semantic markup

Comment: Also, try to be consistent with using quotes around elements attributes values. Some of them are not having quotes at all, ie. <img> tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making it a little more complicated than it needs to be.  Just put two elements as wrappers (one you already have in `alignImage`, set them to display as `inline-block` and then put the `vertical-align` to `middle`, `top`, or whatever you like.  I got rid of all the bizarre padding, which was messing with the display as well.  Looks like that was a holdover from your vertically stacked layout.

**Edit** – You've also got two elements with the ID `alignPhoto`.  You really, really shouldn't do that.  If you need to style two different elements with one rule, please use classes instead.

```css
#alignPhoto {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#alignPhoto img {
  border-radius: 100%;
}
#alignImage {
  position: relative;
}
.alignText {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.titleBoldText { text-align: right; }
```

```html
<div class="alignText">
    <div class="titleBoldText">Mary Smith</div>
    <div id=alignCompany class="titleText">Morris Realty and Investments</div>
</div>
<div id="alignPhoto">
  <div class="circle" id=image role="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/42x42">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 2):

One quick and dirty way to wrap it in a table, as to get your vertical align working without any problems as well.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="alignPhoto" class="titleBoldText">Mary Smith</div>
            <div id="alignCompany" class="titleText">Morris Realty and Investments</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="image/url" alt=""/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7m5s6gd7/

Comment: Hm - we rather stopped using tables for layout some time ago, but it's still a solution

Comment: The other route would be the path as the other answer (wrapping your text next to the wrapper aorund your image), but remember that your wrapper around your text has to be the same size as the wrapper for your image, and then vertical align usually becomes a mess in this case (which it shouldn't, come on CSS)

Comment: @BrianLeishman – Usually becomes a mess, how?  I've never experienced a huge problem with two sibling elements, using `vertical-align: middle` provided they're both `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @JoshBurgess the fact than you need a "helper" element next to the items you want to display vertically aligned set to 100% of the height of the parent is absurd, and also you don't need to have the children set to anything special to get the desired effect. I'll admit tables aren't for everything, but in this case, this is the easiest to maintain and quickest solution that doesn't have any drawbacks

Comment: A helper element?  I have no idea what you're talking about.  Look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/da6n6mwc/).  No helpers, nothing.  Using a table isn't only _semantically_ incorrect, it's a huge amount of unnecessary markup.  Not to mention binding your layout to a rigid structure.

Comment: Whoops, I had a different thought in my head, where trying to center only one element vertically within a container, but in this case, each of the other child elements _are_ the helper element I was talking about. But again, this was titled as a quick and dirty to way to get it done, which is exactly what it is

Answer (score 1):

What about slightly simpler version:
HTML:

```
<div id="alignPhoto">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <p>Mary Smith</p>
        <p>Morris Realty and Investments</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper" id="image" role="image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x200" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-wrapper { float:left; }
.image-wrapper img { border-radius:50%; }
#alignPhoto {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3s2dno6h/1/) for that
Basically you keep both paragraphs of text in one holding div and float it to left. This alone should do the job.

**EDIT:**
To make it even simpler, you can use flexbox for vertical alignment.
I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the more effective and scalable solutions to ensuring elements are placed correctly from left to right are to employ wrapper divs with  `clear:both;`. Inside of these wrapper divs you can use `float:left` or `float:right`. The wrapper divs allow you to generate a new "row".

```css
#alignPhoto {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#profileCompany, #profileName {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
#alignImage {
  float: left;
}
.profileWrapper {
    float:left;
}
/* Below creates a circle for the image passed from the backend */

.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  clear: both;
}
.profileWrapper:after {
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 42px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 42px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid white;
  /* Tweak this to increase triangles height */
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.circle {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="profileWrapper">
        <div id=profileName class="titleBoldText">Mary Smith</div>
        <div id=profileCompany class="titleText">Morris Realty and Investments</div>
    </div>
    <div id="alignPhoto">
      <div class="circle" id=image role="image">
        
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```